# htaccess url rewrite issues

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an issues with my htaccess file rules..

My code redirect all url with http://website.com/secure/* to the CGI-BIN without cgi-bin folder in the url.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^secure/$ /cgi-bin/secure/home.pl
RewriteRule ^secure/?(.*)$ /cgi-bin/secure/$1
```

The problems is: I got a 404 not found if I use:

```
http://website.com/secure  (without last slash)
```

Also, I have try to merge this .htaccess with a http to https (only for this section and not all of entire website.

I don't know if its possible to help me with it and if you have a good tutorial to explain me the basic/complex htaccess coding.

Thanks For your time.

Comment: So to clarify - everything works as you expect except for `http://example.com/secure` without a trailing slash?

Comment: Exactly, It is possible, we need that "secure" and "secure/" rewrite at the same place.

Comment: And you also need https but only for `/secure` URIs?

Comment: yes. /secure and /secure/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, redirect to HTTPS for input URL's matching `/secure`. There are a few ways to approach it with a `RewriteCond`.  We'll do so by matching `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

All that's really missing from your `RewriteRule` is an optional slash in the first rule. I'll add `/?` to the first one and use `(.+)` instead of `(.*)` in the second one.

```
RewriteEngine On

# First redirect to HTTPS if HTTPS isn't already on
# The first RewriteCond makes sure this only matches for /secure
# and doesn't force everything on your site into https.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^secure
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,QSA]

# Then fix the rewrite rules
# Nothing after secure goes to home.pl
RewriteRule ^secure/?$ /cgi-bin/secure/home.pl [L]
# Something present after secure/ (.+) is captured in $1
RewriteRule ^secure/(.+)$ /cgi-bin/secure/$1 [L]
```

If the rewrites into `cgi-bin/` should preserve query strings, use `[L,QSA]` instead of just `[L]`

Comment: Hi Michael,
It work as well!! Thank you for your help (I have add a slash at the first RewriteCond. ^/secure

do you have a tutorial to learn it?

Comment: I don't know of a solid tutorial unfortunately. Just be sure to learn regular expressions well and refer to the Apache official documentation.